# How can I populate what is indexed under the tags metadata field in Maven central?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-central

Maven Central's [search facility](http://search.maven.org/) offers several different fields you can search on.  The most familiar are, of course, group ID, artifact ID and version.  But there are others.  For example, here is a query that searches on a field called `tags`:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ctags%3Asbtplugin

If you choose an artifact in that list and dig into it, you will find indeed that (once you get past the broken links!) the `pom.xml` has an `sbtVersion` property in it.

So maybe, I thought, that's how you get the `tags` field populated: just add an arbitrary property in the `properties` stanza.  Of course, the tag sought above is `sbtplugin` whereas the property checked is `sbtVersion`, so clearly something else is involved, but that mechanism isn't documented anywhere I can find.

**So how *does* this index field get populated?**  Is it a Nexus-specific feature?  Can I populate it using the `maven-deploy-plugin`, whose goals do not seem to hint at such a thing?

Being able to search programmatically on this field would be very, very helpful if I can control what gets put in there.

Comment: I think it it does kind of contains search on description,namegroup and artifact id. I did similar search with 'maven' keyword and check first result: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/cjoop/cjoop-proguard/0.0.2/cjoop-proguard-0.0.2.pom only description field has the keyword 'maven' as text

Comment: Hi, @HRgiger; no, it's definitely not looking at those, or at least not exclusively those.  Note in my question the `sbtplugin` value: you won't find that string _anywhere_ in the resulting artifacts.  It's clearly added somewhere else.

Comment: I think this is a Nexus-specific thing.  See https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html, and search for `tags`; you'll note that at staging time you can specify arbitrary tags.  Presumably then (a) search.maven.org is sitting on top of Nexus and (b) they've indexed the tags.

Comment: For example, this query, taken from the search.maven.org examples (http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=1:%2235379fb6526fd019f331542b4e9ae2e566c57933%22&rows=20&wt=xml) returns one artifact, and you can see some metadata associated with that artifact (look for `tags` in the XML).

Comment: I see you might be correct, I know that maven.org fetches from sonatype I added my plugin there and it was in maven repo after an hour, also i search my plugin with the same name but using tag and it was there

Comment: What's interesting is they obviously generate tags themselves: if you search for a _specific_ artifact then even if you never added tags a tag array will come back.  For example: http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:org.microbean+AND+v:3&wt=xml  I uploaded this, but never added tags; nevertheless you can see them in the output.

Comment: Yes i also checked my ticket there is no tag, but what i find out for @Mojo(name=x) annotation x is placed in the tags for sure (in the source code)

Comment: More information here: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/tree/master/staging/maven-plugin#tagging-staging-repositories  I'll answer my own question when I'm allowed to.

Comment: I think it is different maven http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 schema has tag under scm its decribed as below:  <xs:documentation source="description">
            The tag of current code. By default, it&apos;s set to HEAD during development.
          </xs:documentation>

Comment: Oh no ok you are right

Comment: One other possibility that might be going on behind the scenes: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465338-How-can-I-add-additional-metadata-to-an-artifact-stored-in-Nexus-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joel Orlina of Sonatype writes:

> Older versions of the indexer that backs [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org) populated the `tags` field with the contents of the `<description>` element in the POM.  The field is passed through some standard `StopWord` filters and maybe some other Lucene analyzers, so the full contents won't make it into the `tag`s field.  We made some changes a couple years back to help out the scala/sbt community where, based on specific elements we discover in scala/sbt-plugin poms, we synthesize three tags: `sbtPlugin`, `sbtVersion`, and `scalaVersion`.  This allows users of sbt plugins to search for those types of artifacts, which, in many cases don't conform to the Maven2 repository layout and, as such, don't normally get indexed by the [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/) indexer.
>
> There's not much else to the tags field.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [API description](http://search.maven.org/#api) on the Maven central itself.

> `http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|tags:sbtplugin`
>
> Returns al artifacts in central that are `sbtplugins`. An sbtplugin is
>   defined as an artifact *with a pom including the properties
>   "sbtVersion" and "scalaVersion"*.

Also

> `http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|tags:sbtVersion-0.11`
>
> Returns all artifacts in central *that use sbt version 0.11*

Comment: Thank you, yes; but arbitrary `pom.xml` properties are not where tags come from.  My question is: how is the `tags` index field populated?

Comment: @LairdNelson Haven't tried this, but probably during the release phase. http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html. The release.properties file might have the content created. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html

Comment: No, the `release.properties` file is what the `maven-release-plugin` uses for its `release:perform` goal.

Comment: @Laird Nelson its content specifies a path to a tag name  file as well.

Comment: You're looking at this, I assume: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html#Performing_the_release Note that any reference to "tag" in the context of the `maven-release-plugin` concerns things like `svn` tags or `git` tags, and has nothing to do with Nexus or Maven Central metadata.